# I'm using one foot more than the other: how can I stop doing that?

Tags: running

I noticed that when I'm running I'm using my right foot more than my left foot (I'm right handed). I'm pretty sure that this is bad form. What's the best way to stop doing that?

Comment: How did you diagnose this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using one more than the other? It's running, you use them pretty equally, unless you're hopping. Can you describe your gait, so we have an idea of what you're wanting to correct?

Comment: @Sancho my right foot hurts more than the other (which doesn't hurt), and when I'm running, I'm noticing that that foot is pushing harder and faster than my left.

Comment: @JohnP see [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/im-using-one-foot-more-than-the-other-how-can-i-stop-doing-that#comment10715_7380)

Comment: Ok, if you are running and it is hurting, then you have something else going on. Form may be contributing, but unless something is seriously akimbo, then you have an injury, old shoes, something that needs to be looked at as well.

Comment: So what you really mean to say is that you (over)load one side more than the other and may have lead to an overload injury of the foot?

Comment: Since your right foot is hurt, you could just _feel_ that it is working harder than your left. My answer still stands, but it may not actually address your problem if you've diagnosed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on maintaining an even cadence. You could listen to a metronome app on your phone, or find a song that has the cadence you're trying to achieve. If you maintain an even cadence, you'll likely be using each leg/foot the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that come to mind:

1. Get checked for a leg length discrepancy.  There are solutions.
2. Consider getting some inserts for your shoes.
3. Get one of these: [http://www.amazon.com/Mueller-Jumpers-Knee-Strap-Blue/dp/B000F5R4S6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1342985036&sr=8-1&keywords=mueller+knee+strap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000F5R4S6)
4. When you run, don't swing your arms crazily - this can throw off your entire stride.  Think of your elbows like elbowing somebody directly behind you, not large, flailing motions.
5. Go see a podiatrist, you may have a number of possible problems with your foot.
6. Keep in mind any past injuries.

Comment: I would advise against #6. Focusing on past injuries is a distraction and could cause overcompensation. You should just think of the form you _want_ not the form (or injury) that you _don't_ want.